# How can I concatenate two strings to use as an argument in an initialisation list?

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

I have a class which extends another, so the constructor initialisation list looks like this:

```
MyDialog() : BaseDialog(BaseWindow::getDisplay(), 425, 300, LOC(dialog_title)) {
```

`LOC(dialog_title)` deals with Localisation, it will be replaced with a literal string like `"Dialog Title"`. The problem is I'd like to use another string produced with `LOC`, so that the result would be something like `Dialog Title - Mode`. This requires concatenating three strings, `LOC(dialog_title)`, `" - "` and `LOC(dialog_mode)`. How can I concatenate these within the initialisation list?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the formatted title string in `MyDialog` constructor and send that along to base class?

Comment: @AJG85 Because the constructor is called from a lot of places. It would be much simple to deal with it in the constructor rather than at every place it is called.

Comment: Fair enough, you could probably update your LOC macro or function to use va_args and handle localization as well as concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `LOC` gets replaced by a string literal, then you can simply concatenate them to get a new string literal:

```
LOC(dialog_title) " - " LOC(dialog_mode)
```

Otherwise, the answer depends on whether the base class expects `std::string`:

```
std::string(LOC(dialog_title)) + " - " + LOC(dialog_mode)
```

or a C-style string which it's going to copy into a buffer that it manages:

```
(std::string(LOC(dialog_title)) + " - " + LOC(dialog_mode)).c_str()
```

or a C-style string that it simply keeps a pointer to, in which case the best option is to change the base class to be less evil.

Comment: Hey Mike, are you sure the lifetime of the `std::string` temporary is sufficient in your third example?  (It is not being bound to anything, so doesn't the `c_str()` return become a dangling reference before the constructor even runs?)

Comment: @Nemo: The temporary lasts until the end of the full-expression, so the pointer will be valid during the base-class constructor call, but not for long after it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your `BaseDialog` requires a `const char *`. If that's correct, you could change it to accept a `const std::string&`, or construct that string before calling the constructor, passing it as `yourString.c_str()`.

The benefit of changing it to `const std::string&` is that you won't break any existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the following work?

```
MyDialog() : BaseDialog(BaseWindow::getDisplay(), 425, 300, std::string( LOC(dialog_title) + " - " + LOC(dialog_mode) ) {
```

Comment: I get `error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [4]' to binary 'operator+'`

Comment: Try `std::string(LOC(dialog_title)) + " - " + LOC(dialog_mode)`.

Comment: `error: .... note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'const char*'`

Comment: I can't cast from a `string` to a `const char*` either apparently